# Saving state or view of a page in kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a web application developed using Kendo UI.It has different pages containing filter,search bars,grids etc.

Let there be two pages page A and page B, If I have done some operations on page A (Seach operation and filling a form) then I have navigate to page B to refer some data and came back to the previous page A. But all the operations done on page A (Search and form data) are gone , the page is loaded like a fresh page.

Is there any way to save the state of the page A so that when I came back to page A from page B I will have all my previous work.

```
 $("#landingPage").hide();
    $("#mf").hide();
    $("#wf").show();
    var contentWf="#sd_cont_wf";
//  $("#sd_cont_wf").html("");
    if (!_currentView) {
        constants.sessionDefaults.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        domReady(function () {
            require(["domReady", "app/views/common/home"], function (domReady, homeView) {
                domReady(function () {
                    $('#app-layout').html("");
                    _currentView = new homeView();
                    if (!_app) {
                        showApp();
                        }
                    _app.showIn("#app-layout", _currentView);
                    _currentView.showIn(contentWf, view);
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(".user_settings_menu").hide();
        if(wf==0){
            _currentView.showIn(contentWf, view);
            constants.wfView=_currentView;
//          var htmlData=$(contentWf).html();
//          view.render("#sd_cont_wf");
//          $("#sd_cont_wf").append(view.render);
            wf=1;
        }
}
```

Comment: short answer yes - long answer localstorage/cookies/sessionstoarge/db

Comment: @madalinivascu  But when i tried to reload the saved view from local storage all the handlebars (html) are not getting, only the handlebars loaded during the first time is available.

Comment: you saved the view to localstorage?why? save only the filtered state

Comment: @madalinivascu Because I want the page exactly same when coming back. Not only the filter results. But all the operations done on the page.

Comment: can you provide the code where you save the page to localstorage and how you retrieve your page?

Comment: @madalinivascu I didn't save the code in local storage but each page(the view) is loaded in different "div". The show and hide operation is done on the "div" for getting the required page. 

But when I show a hided "div" I was getting the issue

Comment: by code i mean the javascript code where you do this

Comment: @madalinivascu I have updated the question with the code.